# Generic programming in C

Tags: c, generics, printf, void-pointers, generic-programming

I am writing a generic linked list implementation in pure C.

```
struct Node {
    void *value;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
    struct Node *start;
    struct Node *end;
};

void LinkedList_new(struct LinkedList* llist) {
    llist->start = 0;
    llist->end = 0;
    return;
}

void addNode( struct LinkedList *ll, void *_value ) {
    if ( NULL == ll->start ) {
        ll->start = (struct Node *) malloc( sizeof(struct Node) );
        ll->end = ll->start;
    } else {
        ll->end->next = (struct Node *) malloc( sizeof(struct Node) );
        ll->end = ll->end->next;
    }
    ll->end->value = _value;
    return;
};
```

This all works great. My problem is when I get to printing value to the screen. I can't seem to find a generic implementation for printing.

Is there a way to determine the TYPE allocated to `void *`? (And then just do conversion using a switch statement)

```
void printFunc(int aInt) {
    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", aInt);
    printf(str);
}
```

This is an implementation that works for int. Worst case I was thinking was writing a different function for each TYPE. Is this really my only route when using `void *`?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use  user-supplied function (per function pointer). Like there could be a function to compare for sorting.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`... if you're going generic: a void pointer is all you'll ever need

Comment: For a generic linked-list to actually be a meaningful container ADT, you will need to store the actual data inside it, and not just pointers. This means that you will have to update the `Node` type with a size-in-bytes parameter. And then hard copy the data to/from the linked list whenever a node is created/deleted/searched for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there's no way to figure that out from the pointer alone. That would require type information to be stored at some well-defined location in all run-time structures, which is simply not how C uses the machine.

The common solution is for the user of the datatype to provide the print function that the application needs, since the application *will* know the type of data being stored. That is, there is usually an iteration function that takes a function pointer, calling the user's function (which might print the element) on each element of the list.

Here's how such a function could look:

```
void LinkedList_foreach(const LinkedList *start,
                        bool (*func)(void *element, void *data), void *data);
```

The above should call `func()` for each element of the list, passing it the element's data *and* the additional user-supplied `data` pointer which can be used by the caller to maintain state for the traversal. The callback `func()` should return `false` to stop the iteration, `true` to keep going.

To print an integer, assuming the integers are stored *in the pointers*, you could have:

```
static bool print_int(void *element, void *data)
{
  printf("%d\n", (int) element);
  return true;
}
```

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the developers need to write the print function to use the exact datatype they are using? For the implementation I wrote, I tested the int function with the ```void *``` after I posted this and it didn't work. Is there a way to safely type cast void to say ```int *```? (and eventually others)

Comment: For readability, `typedef` the function pointer. For example `typedef bool (print_func_t)(void *element, void *data);`. And then pass the function pointer to the function as a `const print_func_t*`.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, that's commonly done. Wouldn't make it a `const` pointer though, since that implies functions can be modified which they can't.

Comment: No, the const keyword implies that the function _cannot_ be modified :)

Comment: @Lundin I know; I meant that writing it *without* `const` implies that the function can be modified, which it can't, so the `const` adds nothing.

Comment: With the typedef as I wrote it, it is perhaps not obvious to the reader that the passed type is a function pointer. Whether or not C actually allows you to modify the contents of a function pointer (by abusing the non-const type, like for example the UB you get when you try to access the contents of a string literal), I have no idea.

Comment: Okay, I will give you the right answer. I am learning C, it is interesting the way generics are implemented.

Comment: It is still not clear to me the role of void*data in your print_int .... It is not even used. Can you clarify?